# React Native onEndReached Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

In React Native `FlatList`, *onEndReached* is triggered when the flatlist reached end. Is there any props for reach start?

I want to do something when flatlist reached start.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `onScroll`. And then *onScroll* function will trigger the desired function when beginning is reached. Also set the throttle to '0' to fire changes only twice (once when still scrolling, once when scrolling is finished).

You can also configure the comparison of `contentOffset.y` to compare to the height of content of first items.

Also consider disabling bounce (`bounces` to false) of scrolling on iOS since bounce causes a lag on dispatching the event.

I'd add a snack.expo.io example here, but it seems to be very slow at the moment.

```
<FlatList
  onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (nativeEvent.contentOffset.y === 0) {
      // DO THE MAGIC
    }
  }}
  scrollEventThrottle={0}
  ... />
```

Comment: WoW! Awesome!!! It works on me! Actually, I was working with google for finding the result last 2 days and finally you saved my life! Can I ask additional question?

Comment: @EgorT go ahead, shoot another question and maybe start a chat if needed.

Comment: onEndReached function is called once. Is there any solution to call it everytime?

Comment: I want to call onScroll function once. Any solution?

Comment: Basically `scrollEventThrottle={0}` does it. Once per momentum start and once per momentum stop. You could add a boolean flag which prevents multiple operations inside `onScroll`.